# How to disable case sensitive for route variable in asp net core API?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have this

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("client/{clientid}/employees")]
[SwaggerOperation(Tags = new[] { "Client" })]
public async Task<Unit> AddClientEmployee(AddClientEmployeeCommand request)
{
    return await _mediator.Send(request);
}  

public class AddClientEmployeeCommand : IRequest<Unit>
{
    [FromRoute]
    public Guid ClientId { get; set; }
    [FromBody]
    public Employee Employee { get; set; } = new Employee();
}
```

The `{clientid}` from `Route` won't bind to `AddClientEmployeeCommand.ClientId` unless  I change it to `{ClientId}`. Is there any way to disable case-sensitive for this case?

Comment: camelCase would work, so you could write `client/{clientId}/employees`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you try to bind a class property with `FromRoute` it try to find a route section based on that property name and because the `clientid` is not equal with `ClientId` it won't bind. For solve this you should specify name for property like this:

```cs
 public class AddClientEmployeeCommand : IRequest<Unit>
        {
            [FromRoute(Name = "clientid")]
            public Guid ClientId { get; set; }
            [FromBody]
            public Employee Employee { get; set; } = new Employee();
        }
```

Also for preventing binding error in calling api you can specify type in the route

```
[Route("client/{clientid:guid}/employees")]
```

Comment: you really good there